# Eclipse with vrapper doesn't recognize file changes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a file open in Eclipse. I make some changes (new lines, type some stuff), and it never indicates the file has been changed (with the `*` on the file tab). So I `ctrl+s` to save, close the file, re-open it, and my changes are not there.

#### Context

Eclipse Build Details

- Eclipse Platform
- Version: 2020-06 (4.16)
- Build id: X20200903-1448
- OS: Linux, v.5.8.11-200.fc32.x86_64, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.23, WebKit 2.28.4
- Java version: 11.0.8

Other

- Vrapper (VIM) extension
- PHP project
- Happens in multiple projects
- Only happens in PHP files

#### Reproduce

1. Double click a file to open. Starts in Normal Mode (VIM)
2. go to a line & press `O` to create a new line
3. Type `echo "zeeb"; exit;`

Now, there should be an asterisk next to my filename on the file tab, but there isn't.
At this point, if I click with the mouse & select some text, the asterisk will appear most of the time. Then I can save. Or, if I go back into normal mode, the asterisk appears

#### What I've tried

- Project -> Clean
- Project -> uncheck 'Build Automatically' (same behavior either way)
- Closing all Eclipse windows & re-opening just one window
- Disabling vrapper <- this works! But I need my vim.

Comment: If you can reproduce this bug with the current version of Eclipse (not the outdated you have) and the current version of Vrapper, make sure it has been reported to Vrapper. Maybe there are some hints in the error log what is going wrong here and maybe you can help to fix it. It sounds like you're facing a bug, so which kind of answer do you expect to get here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm on Fedora which doesn't have the latest Eclipse through `dnf`, so it seems. I managed to find a fix, which does seem like a bug, but in their docs they clearly state that atomic inserts cause problems sometimes, so... Think I should still report it to 'em?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `:set noatomicinsert` to `~/.vrapperrc` seems to have fixed it.

[Vrapper Settings](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?topic=configuration) states:

> Whether inserts should be handled as atomic operation. This causes problems sometimes, so it is deactivatable.